# Most powerful test for hypothesis testing with uniform and exponential distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, neyman-pearson-lemma

Given sample of single observation $x_{[1]}$, we are checking hypothesis $H_0 \sim U[0, 1]$ versus $H_1 \sim Exp(1)$. I need to find most powerful test for hypothesis checking with given Type I error level $\alpha = x$ and need to find power of the test ($1 - \beta(x)$) as a function of $x$.

My attempt is: finding the likelihood ratio $r(x) = f_{H_1}/f_{H_0}$, I get the $r(x) = e^{-x}[x \in [0, 1] ]$ and then, using on Neyman-Pearson lemma, I need to find const $c_1$ from resolving $\alpha = P(f_{H_1}/f_{H_0} > c_1)$. However, I can't find the distribution of $r(x)$, so I wonder if I could replace $r(x) = f_{H_1}/f_{H_0}$ using $r(x)$ is monotone? It's non-increasing though, and we need non-decreasing.

Comment: To start: Suppose $\alpha =0.05.$ Makes sense to reject when density of $\mathsf{Exp}(1)$ is highest relative to density of $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1).$ So Reject if $x \le 0.05$ or $x \ge 1,$ Then what is $\beta?$

Comment: @BruceET but why since we used $\alpha = 0.05$ the $x \le 0.05$ and not $x \le 0$? And please note (I didn't mention it, and I will update my post). I don't need to __calculate__ it, but to find __function__ of $x$

Comment: @BruceET I mean, we have that $\alpha = P_{H_0}(r(x) \ge c)$, but to derive this we need to know probability distribution of statistic $r(x)$ assuming $H_0$ is right. We know distribution of $P(e^{-x} [x \in [0, 1]] \ge c)$, which is exponential on [0, 1] interval. But how we can use knowledge of $H_0$ is right? If we could simplify and use something like $P(x [x \in [0, 1]] \ge c)$, we could use this knowledge. But in this conditions idk how to proceed.

Comment: First, draw picture. Second, use common sense. Third, try to reconcile with N-P Lemma. // Critical value and $\alpha$ depend on unif dist'n; $\beta$ and power on exponential.

Comment: @BruceET yes I know which depends on what, I literally wrote that past letter

Comment: Let's try going back to my first comment. For the test described there $\alpha = 0.05.$ What is $\beta?$ // You don't need a complicated equation. Just look at a graph of null and alternative densities and compute. Once you understand that much, you can generalize.